# jQuery jScrollPane not showing in Chrome or Firefox

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane

I'm trying to use jQuery jScrollPane to scroll content in a div element but for some reason it just doesn't show. To try to figure out what's happened I downloaded the demo version online found at http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/basic.html

It seems strange but even that doesn't work: I don't see any scrollbar show up.

As seen in the code below I have literally copied all the source code from the demo file, saved it on my desktop as demo.html, put the relevant css files in a css folder, and js files in a js folder. But no scrollbar showing.

Here is the code I copied:

```
    <title>Basic jScrollPane demo</title> 

    <!-- styles specific to demo site --> 
    <link type="text/css" href="css/demo.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" /> 
    <!-- styles needed by jScrollPane - include in your own sites --> 
    <link type="text/css" href="css/jquery.jscrollpane.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" /> 

    <style type="text/css" id="page-css"> 
        /* Styles specific to this particular page */
        .scroll-pane
        {
            width: 100%;
            height: 200px;
            overflow: auto;
        }
        .horizontal-only
        {
            height: auto;
            max-height: 200px;
        }
    </style> 

    <!-- latest jQuery direct from google's CDN --> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <!-- the mousewheel plugin --> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script> 
    <!-- the jScrollPane script --> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js"></script> 
    <!-- scripts specific to this demo site --> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/demo.js"></script> 

    <script type="text/javascript" id="sourcecode"> 
        $(function()
        {
            $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
        });
    </script> 
</head> 
<body> 
    <div id="top-nav"> 
        <img src="image/logo.png" width="196" height="69" alt="jScrollPane"> 
        <ul> 
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li> 
            <li><a href="index.html#examples">Examples</a></li> 
            <li><a href="index.html#themes">Themes</a></li> 
            <li><a href="index.html#usage">How to use</a></li> 
            <li><a href="faqs.html">FAQs</a></li> 
            <li><a href="known_issues.html">Known issues</a></li> 
            <li><a href="index.html#support">Support</a></li> 
            <li><a href="index.html#download">Download</a></li> 
        </ul> 
    </div> 
    <div id="container"> 
        <h1>jScrollPane - simple demo page</h1> 
        <p> 
            This demonstration shows basic use of the jScrollPane plugin to add scrollbars to a HTML
            element which has an overflow of "auto". Note that with javascript disabled the browsers
            default scrollbars will be used to provide scrolling for the element below. With javascript
            enabled then the browsers default scrollbars will be replaced with jScrollPane scrollbars
            which can be styled at will.
        </p> 

        <h2>Vertical only</h2> 
        <div class="scroll-pane"> 
            <p> 
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec in ligula id sem tristique ultrices
                eget id neque. Duis enim turpis, tempus at accumsan vitae, lobortis id sapien. Pellentesque nec orci
                mi, in pharetra ligula. Nulla facilisi. Nulla facilisi. Mauris convallis venenatis massa, quis
                consectetur felis ornare quis. Sed aliquet nunc ac ante molestie ultricies. Nam pulvinar ultricies
                bibendum. Vivamus diam leo, faucibus et vehicula eu, molestie sit amet dui. Proin nec orci et elit
                semper ultrices. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus
                mus. Sed quis urna mi, ac dignissim mauris. Quisque mollis ornare mauris, sed laoreet diam malesuada
                quis. Proin vel elementum ante. Donec hendrerit arcu ac odio tincidunt posuere. Vestibulum nec risus
                eu lacus semper viverra.
            </p> 
            <p> 
                Vestibulum dictum consectetur magna eu egestas. Praesent molestie dapibus erat, sit amet sodales
                lectus congue ut. Nam adipiscing, tortor ac blandit egestas, lorem ligula posuere ipsum, nec
                faucibus nisl enim eu purus. Quisque bibendum diam quis nunc eleifend at molestie libero tincidunt.
                Quisque tincidunt sapien a sapien pellentesque consequat. Mauris adipiscing venenatis augue ut
                tempor. Donec auctor mattis quam quis aliquam. Nullam ultrices erat in dolor pharetra bibendum.
                Suspendisse eget odio ut libero imperdiet rhoncus. Curabitur aliquet, ipsum sit amet aliquet varius,
                est urna ullamcorper magna, sed eleifend libero nunc non erat. Vivamus semper turpis ac turpis
                volutpat non cursus velit aliquam. Fusce id tortor id sapien porta egestas. Nulla venenatis luctus
                libero et suscipit. Sed sed purus risus. Donec auctor, leo nec eleifend vehicula, lacus felis
                sollicitudin est, vitae lacinia lectus urna nec libero. Aliquam pellentesque, arcu condimentum
                pharetra vestibulum, lectus felis malesuada felis, vel fringilla dolor dui tempus nisi. In hac
                habitasse platea dictumst. Ut imperdiet mauris vitae eros varius eget accumsan lectus adipiscing.
            </p> 
            <p> 
                Quisque et massa leo, sit amet adipiscing nisi. Mauris vel condimentum dolor. Duis quis ullamcorper
                eros. Proin metus dui, facilisis id bibendum sed, aliquet non ipsum. Aenean pulvinar risus eu nisi
                dictum eleifend. Maecenas mattis dolor eget lectus pretium eget molestie libero auctor. Praesent sit
                amet tellus sed nibh convallis semper. Curabitur nisl odio, feugiat non dapibus sed, tincidunt ut
                est. Nullam erat velit, suscipit aliquet commodo sit amet, mollis in mauris. Curabitur pharetra
                dictum interdum. In posuere pretium ultricies. Curabitur volutpat eros vehicula quam ultrices
                varius. Proin volutpat enim a massa tempor ornare. Sed ullamcorper fermentum nisl, ac hendrerit sem
                feugiat ac. Donec porttitor ullamcorper quam. Morbi pretium adipiscing quam, quis bibendum diam
                congue eget. Sed at lectus at est malesuada iaculis. Sed fermentum quam dui. Donec eget ipsum dolor,
                id mollis nisi. Donec fermentum vehicula porta.
            </p> 
            <p> 
                Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
                Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero
                sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.
                Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed,
                commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros
                ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis.
                Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna
                eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis
                luctus, metus
            </p> 
            <p> 
                Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
                Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit
                amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.
            </p> 
        </div> 
        <h2>Horizontal only</h2> 
        <div class="scroll-pane horizontal-only"> 
            <p style="width: 1000px;"> 
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec in ligula id sem tristique ultrices
                eget id neque. Duis enim turpis, tempus at accumsan vitae, lobortis id sapien. Pellentesque nec orci
                mi, in pharetra ligula. Nulla facilisi. Nulla facilisi. Mauris convallis venenatis massa, quis
                consectetur felis ornare quis. Sed aliquet nunc ac ante molestie ultricies. Nam pulvinar ultricies
                bibendum. Vivamus diam leo, faucibus et vehicula eu, molestie sit amet dui. Proin nec orci et elit
                semper ultrices. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus
                mus. Sed quis urna mi, ac dignissim mauris. Quisque mollis ornare mauris, sed laoreet diam malesuada
                quis. Proin vel elementum ante. Donec hendrerit arcu ac odio tincidunt posuere. Vestibulum nec risus
                eu lacus semper viverra.
            </p> 
        </div> 
        <h2>Both</h2> 
        <div class="scroll-pane"> 
            <p style="width: 1000px"> 
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec in ligula id sem tristique ultrices
                eget id neque. Duis enim turpis, tempus at accumsan vitae, lobortis id sapien. Pellentesque nec orci
                mi, in pharetra ligula. Nulla facilisi. Nulla facilisi. Mauris convallis venenatis massa, quis
                consectetur felis ornare quis. Sed aliquet nunc ac ante molestie ultricies. Nam pulvinar ultricies
                bibendum. Vivamus diam leo, faucibus et vehicula eu, molestie sit amet dui. Proin nec orci et elit
                semper ultrices. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus
                mus. Sed quis urna mi, ac dignissim mauris. Quisque mollis ornare mauris, sed laoreet diam malesuada
                quis. Proin vel elementum ante. Donec hendrerit arcu ac odio tincidunt posuere. Vestibulum nec risus
                eu lacus semper viverra.
            </p> 
            <p> 
                Vestibulum dictum consectetur magna eu egestas. Praesent molestie dapibus erat, sit amet sodales
                lectus congue ut. Nam adipiscing, tortor ac blandit egestas, lorem ligula posuere ipsum, nec
                faucibus nisl enim eu purus. Quisque bibendum diam quis nunc eleifend at molestie libero tincidunt.
                Quisque tincidunt sapien a sapien pellentesque consequat. Mauris adipiscing venenatis augue ut
                tempor. Donec auctor mattis quam quis aliquam. Nullam ultrices erat in dolor pharetra bibendum.
                Suspendisse eget odio ut libero imperdiet rhoncus. Curabitur aliquet, ipsum sit amet aliquet varius,
                est urna ullamcorper magna, sed eleifend libero nunc non erat. Vivamus semper turpis ac turpis
                volutpat non cursus velit aliquam. Fusce id tortor id sapien porta egestas. Nulla venenatis luctus
                libero et suscipit. Sed sed purus risus. Donec auctor, leo nec eleifend vehicula, lacus felis
                sollicitudin est, vitae lacinia lectus urna nec libero. Aliquam pellentesque, arcu condimentum
                pharetra vestibulum, lectus felis malesuada felis, vel fringilla dolor dui tempus nisi. In hac
                habitasse platea dictumst. Ut imperdiet mauris vitae eros varius eget accumsan lectus adipiscing.
            </p> 
            <p> 
                Quisque et massa leo, sit amet adipiscing nisi. Mauris vel condimentum dolor. Duis quis ullamcorper
                eros. Proin metus dui, facilisis id bibendum sed, aliquet non ipsum. Aenean pulvinar risus eu nisi
                dictum eleifend. Maecenas mattis dolor eget lectus pretium eget molestie libero auctor. Praesent sit
                amet tellus sed nibh convallis semper. Curabitur nisl odio, feugiat non dapibus sed, tincidunt ut
                est. Nullam erat velit, suscipit aliquet commodo sit amet, mollis in mauris. Curabitur pharetra
                dictum interdum. In posuere pretium ultricies. Curabitur volutpat eros vehicula quam ultrices
                varius. Proin volutpat enim a massa tempor ornare. Sed ullamcorper fermentum nisl, ac hendrerit sem
                feugiat ac. Donec porttitor ullamcorper quam. Morbi pretium adipiscing quam, quis bibendum diam
                congue eget. Sed at lectus at est malesuada iaculis. Sed fermentum quam dui. Donec eget ipsum dolor,
                id mollis nisi. Donec fermentum vehicula porta.
            </p> 
            <p> 
                Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
                Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero
                sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.
                Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed,
                commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros
                ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis.
                Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna
                eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis
                luctus, metus
            </p> 
            <p> 
                Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
                Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit
                amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.
            </p> 
        </div> 
        <h2>Page javascript</h2> 
        <div id="sourcecode-display"> 
            <p>The contents of this div will be replaced by the javascript added to this page</p> 
        </div> 
        <h2>Page CSS</h2> 
        <div id="css-display"> 
            <p>The contents of this div will be replaced by the CSS added to this page</p> 
        </div> 
    </div> 
</body>
```

Any help MUCH appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your script paths are messed up, I copied your source and rewrote the scrollpane script and css urls to point to the versions I happen to currently have at my localhost. All works fine.

Check the error console, it should say that jScrollPane is not a function, meaning the plugin just failed to load.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I rechecked the error console but don't get the error you suggest. I've uploaded the files I'm using so maybe you could take a look at those to get a better idea of where I'm getting mixed up - http://www.qfpost.com/download.do?get=e355dff885d7772eb44322afb1baf00b

Comment: Sorry that link is no good... you can check out the source code I'm using at http://www.studiorav.co.uk/demo.zip thank you,

Comment: Ok I believe I may have got a step further... I downloaded the js files again and this time using the unminified version the demo file works! My own file doesn't... but at least now I can compare it to another working file... Thanks!!